# How to send SMS using Oracle's Responsys API in .Net

Tags: .net, oracle, web-services, api, oracle11g

I want to send SMS using Oracle's Responsys API in a .NET project. However I can't find a suitable way to do this. Please provide me the solution either in C# or on VB.